# Options shuffle each time a webpage is reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I’m working on a web application where users can take a quiz. I’m currently using twenty questions and I want the options to shuffle each time the page is refreshed. How can I do this using JS or any of its frameworks?

Comment: do you need a specific order, or a guarantee of not repeating a given pattern?

Comment: Assuming your questions are in an array like object you probably want to shuffle them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: @JonSG interesting; I tried this solution (or a similar one) and it wouldn't scramble an array of objects: https://jsfiddle.net/5019mgu2/1/

Comment: @dandavis, I don't want any pattern repeated.

Comment: then you need to sort on the server and record which orders have been used. Also, it might not be ethical to show different students different ordering: some could get stuck on a hard question at first, which leaves them less time to answer other questions than students who answer the hard one last.

Comment: @dandavis, what if I use a specific order? Is there a way I can do that from the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```js
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

var questions = [
  { id: 1, name: "question 1" },
  { id: 2, name: "question 2" },
  { id: 3, name: "question 3" },
  { id: 4, name: "question 4" },
  { id: 5, name: "question 5" }
];

shuffleArray(questions);

questions.forEach(function(question){ console.log(question.name); });
```